# Error in hclust(d, method = method) : NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 10)

Tags: r, pheatmap

I am trying to create a heatmap with the package pheatmap in R. I encounter this error:
`Error in hclust(d, method = method) : NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 10)`

```
data <- structure(list(`2LM410` = c(0.4, 0.4, 0.222222222222222, 0.125, 
0.125, 0.5, 0.5, 0.375, 0.4, 0.714285714285714, 0.285714285714286, 
0.5, 0.4, 0.333333333333333, 0.428571428571429, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 
0.428571428571429, 0.571428571428571, 0.75, 0.75), `2LM411` = c(0.222222222222222, 
0.25, 0.285714285714286, 0.285714285714286, 0.285714285714286, 
0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.454545454545455, 0.4, 0.272727272727273, 0.2, 
0.333333333333333, 0.6, 0.5, 0.5, 0.333333333333333, 0.285714285714286, 
0.285714285714286, 0.285714285714286, 0.111111111111111, 0.125
), `2LM413` = c(0.142857142857143, 0, 0.111111111111111, 0.222222222222222, 
0, 0.4, 0.4, 0.5, 0.230769230769231, 0.166666666666667, 0.153846153846154, 
0.583333333333333, 0.545454545454545, 0.538461538461538, 0.692307692307692, 
0.692307692307692, 0.6, 0.7, 0.636363636363636, 0.636363636363636, 
0.8, 0.8), `2LM414` = c(0.875, 0.75, 0.909090909090909, 1, 0.909090909090909, 
0.4375, 0.4, 0.411764705882353, 0.5, 0.4, 0.363636363636364, 
0.222222222222222, 0.125, 0, 0.142857142857143, 0, 0, 0, 0.25, 
0, 0.2, 0), `2LM415` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `2LM417` = c(0.863636363636364, 
0.304347826086957, 0.818181818181818, 0.904761904761905, 0.714285714285714, 
0.961538461538462, 0.961538461538462, 0.964285714285714, 0.923076923076923, 
0.954545454545455, 0.904761904761905, 0, 0.0588235294117647, 
0.117647058823529, 0, 0, 0, 0.0714285714285714, 0.0666666666666667, 
0.0666666666666667, 0, 0), `2LM418` = c(0.666666666666667, 0.666666666666667, 
0.714285714285714, 0.714285714285714, 0.714285714285714, 0.4, 
0.333333333333333, 0.571428571428571, 0.714285714285714, 0.272727272727273, 
0.454545454545455, 0.25, 0.25, 0.2, 0.25, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 
0.2, 0.2, 0.2), `2LM419` = c(0.375, 0.375, 0.5, 0.5, 0.285714285714286, 
0.545454545454545, 0.545454545454545, 0.8, 1, 0.888888888888889, 
0.583333333333333, 0.4, 0.266666666666667, 0.5625, 0.588235294117647, 
0.473684210526316, 0.35, 0.476190476190476, 0.238095238095238, 
0.333333333333333, 0.235294117647059, 0.235294117647059), `2LM420` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.4, 0.285714285714286, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.142857142857143), `2LM421` = c(0.857142857142857, 
0.714285714285714, 0.875, 1, 0.444444444444444, 0.8, 0.785714285714286, 
0.818181818181818, 0.833333333333333, 0.9, 0.8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `2LM422` = c(1, 1, 0.923076923076923, 0.916666666666667, 
0.857142857142857, 0.846153846153846, 0.846153846153846, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.846153846153846, 0.933333333333333, 0.9375, 
0.9375, 0.894736842105263, 0.947368421052632, 0.944444444444444, 
0.944444444444444), `2LM423` = c(0.8, 0.2, 0.8, 1, 0.8, 0.571428571428571, 
0.571428571428571, 0.428571428571429, 0.5, 0.571428571428571, 
0.714285714285714, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
), `2LM424` = c(0, 0, 0, 0.75, 0.75, 1, 1, 1, 0.857142857142857, 
1, 1, 0.875, 0.857142857142857, 0.875, 0.75, 0.777777777777778, 
0.875, 0.75, 0.444444444444444, 0.666666666666667, 0.571428571428571, 
0.428571428571429), `2LM426` = c(0.0909090909090909, 0.1, 0.0833333333333333, 
0.25, 0.181818181818182, 0.157894736842105, 0.0526315789473684, 
0.142857142857143, 0, 0.266666666666667, 0.176470588235294, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `2LM427` = c(0.125, 0, 0.0833333333333333, 
0.230769230769231, 0.153846153846154, 0.2, 0.25, 0.3, 0.363636363636364, 
0.3125, 0.176470588235294, 0.181818181818182, 0.222222222222222, 
0.333333333333333, 0.222222222222222, 0.111111111111111, 0.3, 
0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0.333333333333333, 0.125, 
0.125), `2LM428` = c(0, 0, 0, 0.25, 0, 0, 0.125, 0, 0.222222222222222, 
0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 0.142857142857143, 0, 0, 
0.166666666666667, 0, 0, 0.142857142857143, 0.142857142857143, 
0.285714285714286, 0, 0), `2LM429` = c(0.6, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 0.75, 
0.857142857142857, 0.857142857142857, 0.5, NA, 0.666666666666667, 
0.75, 0.666666666666667, 0.916666666666667, 0.727272727272727, 
0.8, 0.818181818181818, 0.818181818181818, 0.8, 0.75, 0.727272727272727, 
0.25, 0.454545454545455), `2LM430` = c(0.4, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0, 
0, 0, NA, NA, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `2LM431` = c(0.6, 
0.555555555555556, 0.625, 0.75, 0.75, 0.818181818181818, 0.75, 
0.692307692307692, 0.6, 0.7, 0.7, 0.666666666666667, 0.75, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `2LM432` = c(0.230769230769231, 
0.153846153846154, 0.1875, 0.1875, 0.1875, 0.294117647058824, 
0.294117647058824, 0.285714285714286, 0.375, 0.0833333333333333, 
0, 0.0769230769230769, 0.0909090909090909, 0.142857142857143, 
0.142857142857143, 0.1, 0.1, 0.222222222222222, 0.125, 0.111111111111111, 
0, 0), `2LM433` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, 0.2, NA, 0, 0.25, 
0, 0, 0, 0.0909090909090909, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `2LM434` = c(0.6875, 
0.5, 0.733333333333333, 0.785714285714286, 0.285714285714286, 
0.166666666666667, 0.142857142857143, 0.4, 0.285714285714286, 
0.4375, 0.470588235294118, 0.5, 0.5, 0.555555555555556, 0.555555555555556, 
0.571428571428571, 0.4, 0.4, 0.6, 0.75, 0.714285714285714, 0.714285714285714
), `2LM435` = c(0.5, 0.142857142857143, 0.375, 0.375, 0.375, 
0.222222222222222, 0.333333333333333, 0.375, 0.375, 0.5, 0.6, 
0.333333333333333, 0.384615384615385, 0.545454545454545, 0.454545454545455, 
0.5, 0.444444444444444, 0.444444444444444, 0.444444444444444, 
0.444444444444444, 0.5, 0.5), `2LM436` = c(0.4, 0.25, 0.6, 0.75, 
0.75, 0, 0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.555555555555556, 0.571428571428571, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0.142857142857143, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `2LM437` = c(0.538461538461538, 
0.416666666666667, 0.5, 0.583333333333333, 0.583333333333333, 
0.176470588235294, 0.176470588235294, 0.153846153846154, 0.384615384615385, 
0.214285714285714, 0.0666666666666667, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0), `2LM438` = c(0.875, 0.75, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.909090909090909, 
0.9, 0.9, 0.916666666666667, 0.909090909090909, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0.8, 1), `2LM439` = c(0.636363636363636, 0.2, 0.6, 0.6, 
0.777777777777778, 0.2, 0.4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.8, 0.75, 0.7, 0.666666666666667, 
0.6, 0.5, 0.5, 0.375, 0.5, 0.285714285714286, 0.142857142857143
), `2LM440` = c(0.916666666666667, 0.166666666666667, 1, 1, 0.714285714285714, 
0.714285714285714, 0.384615384615385, 0.5625, 1, 1, 1, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `2LM441` = c(0.2, 0.1, 0.2, 
0.5, 0.375, 0, 0, 0.142857142857143, 0.181818181818182, 0.636363636363636, 
0.454545454545455, 0.714285714285714, 0.75, 0.75, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `2LM442` = c(0.75, 0, 0.333333333333333, 
0.5, 0.333333333333333, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.181818181818182, 0, 
0, 0.25, 0.2, NA, 0.25, 0.25, 0.2, 0.2, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 
0.166666666666667, 0.333333333333333), `2LM443` = c(0.444444444444444, 
0.333333333333333, 0.375, 0.5, 0.571428571428571, 0.111111111111111, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.166666666666667, 0, 0, 0.125, 0.142857142857143, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `2LM444` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 0.428571428571429, 0.5, 0.5, 0.428571428571429, 0.428571428571429, 
0.428571428571429, 0.428571428571429, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 
0.4, 0.4)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -22L))
```

and I try many methods to solve it, but it does't work
the data don't have all the 0 or NA rows/cols, and even the 2LM415 column have 0 SD, it can work with `pheatmap(data[,1:5])`

Lastly, I found that this could be the reason of triggering error , but i want to know why it can do that

```
pheatmap(data[, c(5, 32)])
```

Comment: Looking at the matrix `data[, c(5, 32)]`, you can see that each of its rows has an NA.